# Center text in col-md-4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I center (horizontally and vertically) the text inside `<p>`, inside a col-md-4 --> row --> bootstrap.

My code is the next:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Videoclub</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5 style="text-align: center;"><u><i>Informacion</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Acerca de Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contactanos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trabaja con Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prensa</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5 style="text-align: center;"><u><i>Social</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/fb.jpg" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/twitter.png" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/Linkedin.png" alt="FB" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried css with `<p>` tag,

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
```

And it's not working.

I tried another css as well:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

But I just got a horizontally centering

Comment: `text-align: center` should work to center text inside any block element so long as that element is not floated. In regards to vertical alignment, make sure you have no default, or vendor style, `margin` rules set on the `p` element and adjust the `line-height`

Comment: The `p` and the `div` have no height of their own, they get their height from the text. But without the css for the `row`, `div`, `col-md-4` and the `p` it's hard to say what's best to change.

Comment: Setting a fixed height to the <p> resolves the problem vertically, but not horizontally @Calaris

Comment: I am not using vendor styles, just bootstrap... @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: Vendor styles are default browser styles, you end up using them whether you intend to or not (thanks browsers!), that's why resetting default browser styles can help negate these vendor styles.

Comment: How can I reset default browser styles? Thanks @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: You just declare your own custom styles that over-qualify the default vendor styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with ***Flexbox***:

```
.container > .row > .col-md-4:first-child {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontally centered */
  align-items: center; /* vertically centered */
}
```

*Basic CSS browser reset:*

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add : style="text-align: center;" 
like this:

```
  <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;" >
   <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Videoclub</p> </div>
```

or you can add extra class to the div and add in the css style like this:

```css
.extraClass{
text-align:center;
vertical-align:central;
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 extraClass">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Videoclub</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5><u><i>Informacion</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Acerca de Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contactanos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trabaja con Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prensa</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5><u><i>Social</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/fb.jpg" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/twitter.png" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/Linkedin.png" alt="FB" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can also add to the div the property :  vertical-align:central;